# Jquery .live works but not with .datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, datepicker

Thanks for looking, all sincerely helpful answers are up-voted.
I have some date input fields that are there when the page loads and a bunch that get generated dynamically. Instead of calling .datepicker() on that class each time a new instance is generated, I'm using .live, but it doesn't seem to be working. Any idea why?

```
$("input[name=myfav]").live("click", function(){
    $(this).datepicker({ 
        /* some options here */ 
    });
});
```

I should mention, it works perfectly fine with autocomplete for instance.

```
$("input[name=mytwo]").live("click", function(){
    $(this).autocomplete("somefile.php");
});
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is an article about the datepicker using the .live-event in jQuery:

http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-ajax-and-livequery/

The problem is that the Datepicker works by binding to the focus() event by default, but as of jQuery 1.3.2, the ‘focus’ event cannot be monitored by the ‘live’ event function.

Here is the work-around from the site::

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('input.calendarSelectDate').live('click', function() {
        $(this).datepicker({showOn:'focus'}).focus();
    });
});
</script>
```

---

*EDIT: This workaround is no longer needed as jQuery 1.4.1+ now supports focus and blur events for live(). (Thanks [@Chris S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585918/jquery-live-works-but-not-with-datepicker/3617159#3617159))*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I knew it was plugin related since the other plugins work fine. This clarifies it.

Comment: Ran into the same problem. Another part of making this work, for us, was making sure each datepicker input had a unique ID. Otherwise, at least in Google Chrome, you could click in any of the inputs and get a datepicker, but it would actually change the date in the first one with that ID. (Of course, semantically, IDs should always be unique, anyway, but that was the bug.)

Comment: I still had trouble getting the datepicker to close after selecting it. Tried moving the focus to the next input but it wouldn't work. So, onClose, I destroy the datepicker, then on click, I re-bind. Kind of a hack, but it works for me for now.

Answer (score 8):

This is what I ended up using. It takes advantage of `live` and `focus` in newer jQuery

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', ... });
$('input.date').live('focus', function() {
    $(this).datepicker().datepicker('show');
    true;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Worth noting that jQuery 1.4.1+ now supports focus and blur events for live(), so the workaround, whilst cool, is no longer needed - the orignal poster's version works fine!

Comment: It didn't quite work for me but $(".date").live("focus",function() {
  $(this).datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
  })
 }); did

Answer (score 0):

Update : As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. 1.7, Use .on() to attach event handlers. Reference : http://api.jquery.com/live/