# Apply jquery functions to loaded elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I'm trying to apply functions on loaded element, I search the web but i don't understand what to do.

Can anyone tell me what to do?

Example:

```
 <script>
 // checkbox cheque
$("#cheque").click( function () {
        if($("#cheque").is(":checked"))
        {
            //alert('Cheque is checked');
            $("#load_cheque").load("./server/mode_paiement.php?cheque=1");
        }
        else
        {
            //alert('Unchecked Cheque!!');  
            $("#load_cheque").empty();  
        }
    });
  </script>
```

And this is the element to load:

```
<label for=" echeance " class="form-label size-120 fl-space2">Echéance: <span class="required">*</span></label> 
<input type="text" id="echeance" class="required text fl-space2 datepicker-inline" name="echeance"  />
```

as you notice there is "datepicker-inline" .. the probleme is that datepicker is not working on the loaded input

Thanks :)

Comment: I think you have given partially code, also what exactly are you trying to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use '[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)' when binding your datepicker, like this:

```
$('.datepicker-inline').live('click', function() {
        $(this).datepicker({showOn:'focus'}).focus();
});
```

(shamelessly lifted from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585918/jquery-live-works-but-not-with-datepicker))

Otherwise, your datepicker-binding code will not see the new elements to convert to datepickers (they did not exist when it first ran), and you get your current behaviour.

Comment: you should accept it (checkbox icon) if it works, or upvote if the answer is good but not the best.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to use the website.. Maybe  it's too late but I checked the icon. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a callback in the `load` call, which will be called when the new content has been added:

```
$("#load_cheque").load("./server/mode_paiement.php?cheque=1", function(){
  // Here you can fix the loaded content
});
```