# After content is loaded using .load, JqueryRotate stops working

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic, load

I'm using AJAX for load content into a div, I haven't found another way to achieve what I need. I have a playlist on top and everytime the user cliked on a new page the song started again so I had to use AJAX for load the content without reloading the page.

Then I got the first problem: the content I load works perfect if I include Jquery and the plugin needed for that content in the loaded file itself, in this case, a slider but when the content is loaded **JqueryRotate** stops working.

I am using **JqueryRotate** for the buttons that load the content, when you hover them, it rotates a circle but when you click one of those buttons, the content is loaded and the the rotation doesn't work anymore. **Buttons are outside the placed content.**

The client wants that rotation effect so I can't just skip that plugin (I would love to, since everything else works perfect).

I was using all the plugins togheter and they worked perfectly, then client requested me to keep the playlist playing while you navigate to the other pages, so I had to .load the content and then I got that first issue.

The code I'm using for the buttons to rotate:

```
$("#boton").hover( 
   function () {
            $(".img").rotate({animateTo:180})
        },
         function () {
            $(".img").rotate({animateTo:0})
        }
);
```

This other for a dropdown menu:

```
    $('#boton').click(function () {
$('#dsubmenu').toggle(),
$('.tsubmenu, .tmsubmenu').hide();});
```

What options do I have? Should I search for another plugin? I've been browsing and this one is the smallest and the most efficient. I don't wanna change the whole site for just a button, so CSS3 could be another option? Thanks in advance for your answer!

[EDIT Solved!!: I leave the solution here in case someone has a similar problem]

I did what Guffa said in this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186483/apply-jquery-functions-to-loaded-elements):

> You can put a callback in the load call, which will be called when the new content has been added:
>   `$("#load_cheque").load("./server/mode_paiement.php?cheque=1", function(){
>     // Here you can fix the loaded content
>   });`

I included all the .js of the plugins in the main xhtml with header.js, then I loaded the content via AJAX and in the callback added the function for the slider to work, same with the other pages. Thanks Guffa! You saved me!

Answer (score 0):

try using `.getScript` ( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ )