# Making datepicker live - JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I know when you create an element dynamically, you have to use something like:

```
$("#id").live("click", function() {
    //something
});
```

Right now I have this:

```
$('#tdInput1').datepicker({
    inline: true
});
```

My question is: how do I make this *live* so it can interact with dynamically created elements.

Comment: So you want to run `.datepicker({})` on certain elements as they are dynamically loaded into the DOM?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to: [Jquery .live works but not with .datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585918/jquery-live-works-but-not-with-datepicker)

This should work:

```
$("#tdInput1").live("click", function(){
    $(this).datepicker({ 
        inline: true 
    });
});
```

edit: This answer is for older versions of jQuery. For jQuery 1.9+ please try Vishal's answer.

Answer (score 20):

The accepted solution won't work with keyboard focus events.. so I had to change to this:

```
$('.parent').on('focusin', '.datepicker', function(e) {
    $(this).datepicker(options);
});
```

Had to change `.live` to `.on` since jquery 1.9.1 doesn't include the `.live` method. The above works for the mouse events as well as keyboard focus events.

Comment: i have tried this only, but its giving me error that no datepicker method is there. Can you help me

Comment: @Sanyamjain which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: i am using 1.9.1 version. if i write $('#datepicker').datepicker();, it works fine, but if i use on click method, it says no method is there datepicker

Answer (score 7):

You're dealing with two different things. jQuery's `live` is for event binding, while `datepicker` is not specifically tied to an event, but rather just adds functionality to an element at a moment in time.

The only reason `live` works with events is that jQuery actually attaches the event handler to an ancestor element, and (thanks to the way events bubble up in javascript), the ancestor actually receives the event and delegates it as if it came from the element. The principle is kind of complicated, but long and short, it could only work with events.

If you want to add datepicker functionality, simply call the `datepicker` function on the new element after it's created.

Comment: thanks.. have been trying to solve this for long till i found your answer

Answer (score 0):

I think that more proper solution is:

```
$('input.datepickerClass').live('focus', function(){
    if (false == $(this).hasClass('hasDatepicker')) {
        $(this).datepicker({ options });
    }
});
```

Comment: Please avoid source code only answers - explain what you're doing so readers understand what you're trying to say and why.