# datepicker not working into new tabs

Tags: tabs, datepicker

When I click. Datepicker not working into new tabs
This is code

```
<script>
var tabCounter = 2,
    tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>";
var tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
var tabContentHtml = $("#tabs-1").html();
```

Create datepicker. Work into tab1. Not work into tab2

```
$( ".rush" ).datepicker();
```

Add new tabs when click button

```
$("#add_tab").click(function(){
        addTab();
});
function addTab() {
        var label = "Tab " + tabCounter,
            id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
            li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, "#" + id ).replace( /#\{label\}/g, label ) );

        tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
        tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>" );
        tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
        tabCounter++;
    }
</script>
```

Code html

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close">Remove Tab</span></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <input type="text" class="rush" />
</div>
</div>
<button id="add_tab">Add Tab</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is because the datepicker stuff is done when the page is loaded. When you add a new tab, the datepicker is not being created, have a look at the previous post:

[Making datepicker live - JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601301/making-datepicker-live-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call datepicker after creating the new tab:

```
$("#add_tab").click(function(){
    addTab();
    $( ".rush" ).datepicker(); //or your new datepicker id
});
```