# $("datepicker").getdate() not working into new tabs

Tags: jquery, datepicker, getdate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [datepicker not working into new tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009404/datepicker-not-working-into-new-tabs)

When I click button "add tab". Jquery will create **new tab** and **new datepicker** for me. But I can't get date on new datepicker. It is null.
How to selector new datepicker into new tabs ??

My code

```
<script>
var tabCounter = 2,
    tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>";
var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
var tabContentHtml = $("#tabs-1").html();
```

Create datepicker

```
datepicker();
```

Function create picker

```
function datepicker(){
  $( ".rush" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      minDate: myDate,
      onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        // day is null for new tabs
        var day = $( ".rush" ).datepicker('getDate').getDate();
      }
  });
}
```

Add new tabs when click button

```
$("#add_tab").click(function(){
        addTab();
});
function addTab() {
        var label = "Tab " + tabCounter,
            id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
            li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, "#" + id ).replace(/#\{label\}/g, label ) );

        tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
        tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>" );
        tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
        // Create new datepicker into new tabs
        datepicker();
        tabCounter++;
    }
</script>
```

Code html

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close">Remove Tab</span></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <input type="text" class="rush" />
</div>
</div>
<button id="add_tab">Add Tab</button>
```

Comment: No. Here I have question about "Selector". How to selector new datepicker into new tabs ?

Comment: you haven't have passed any element on new tab to be made datepicker for example you do not have any txtBox with class rush to be made datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Try replace `$( ".rush" ).datepicker('getDate').getDate();` by `$(this).datepicker('getDate').getDate();` to avoid selectiopn confusion in your function.

```
function datepicker(){
  $( ".rush" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      minDate: myDate,
      onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        // day is null for new tabs
        var day = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getDate();
      }
  });
}
```