# Javascript in update panel doesn't work after partial postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.datePicker').datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" class="datePicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="holder" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl_RespondBy" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">1 Hour</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_RespondBy" class="datePicker" Visible="true" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl_RespondBy" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>

protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddl_RespondBy.SelectedItem.Text == "Other")
        {
            txt_RespondBy.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

I do partial post back with the update panel, I have two text box one outside update panel and one inside, when I select other from the dropdown and try to open the calendar inside the txt_RespondBy text box it doesn't show, but the text box outside update panel shows the calendar. why is Javascript not working inside update panel after partial postback

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Place your datetimepicker initialisation code in the pageLoad function, which is called whenever the page loads (asynchronously or synchronously).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        $('.datePicker').datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    }      
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pageLoad` or `.live`:

Reference info:
[$(document).ready() and pageLoad() are not the same](http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/)

**.live:**

[Jquery .live works but not with .datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585918/jquery-live-works-but-not-with-datepicker)

```
$(function(){
    $('.datePicker').live('click', function() {
        $(this).datepicker({showOn:'focus'}).focus();
    });
});
```

**pageLoad():**

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    $('.datePicker').datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is a old question but then also I am posting one more answer here if someone visit this page now or in later times for help.
one can use

> $(document).on()

as it makes sure that controls bind to the events whenever page loads. Its job is Similar to page load event but you can say syntax is different. And almost for anything and everything this works. I have more than 50 controls in a panel and all to perform different task and I never got into trouble.. not even once as i was using this function.

```
     $(document).on('eventName', 'element' , function(){
     //your code to perform some task; 
});
```

> eventName can be any event - like click, change, select..

And

> Element - can be a name, classname, id

example - as above question -

> html -

```
<script src="lib/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="datePicker" data-provide="datepicker-inline" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
```

> Javascript -

```
$(function(){
     $(document).on('click', '.datePicker' , function(){
     $(this).datepicker();
    });
});
```